# How can I prevent Google Sites sending all my hyperlinks via their redirect page?

Tags: google-sites

I'm setting up a website using Google Sites.

If I add a hyperlink to a page and select 'Web Address', then enter `http://www.example.com` as the link, the actual page ends up being rendered with

```
http://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.example.com
```

as the hyperlink address. This injects an annoying 'redirecting you to www.example.com' Google page and a two-second delay into following hyperlinks off my page.

Is there any way to turn this behaviour off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever was causing this behaviour, it seems to have stopped after a few days. No idea why, but I'll call that a fix - the site was very new at the time I posted, so possibly it's something to do with Google tracking people filling pages with dubious links?

Answer (score 1):

"If the site you're linking to isn't public, it will automatically redirect through *www.google.com/url* when opened to keep the site's anonymity."

Source: [support.google.com/sites/answer/90538](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/90538?hl=en)